# text on website is not displaying on IE10

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

***Problem with IE10***

I've just create a new site for our company: http://mobilereality.pl/ and I'm so close to finish it but now I'm facing up to some problems with this site in IE 10 on Win7. I don't know why but on IE10 site have not bigger part of text. I can say that IE is displaying absolutely nothing apart from some pictures and sections. Furthermore, this is website with two languages and when I was making this I was using AngularJS. Scope contains data and you can change this with clicking on lang button. I'm going to say that all text on this website is part of scope in AngularJS and when we run this site on IE10 we can not see a text on website but in the Contact Section on bottom of website we can, which is making me more confounded. If someone know how to solve this problem I will be  grateful. Really I need help with this. I was looking for similar problem but I didn't find something helpfull. There is picture : [website on IE10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR1ke.png)

Comment: This question is vague. AngularJS works perfectly fine with IE10, please show some code / errors... http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Add a doctype declaration and fix the validation errors. The extra `<html>` tag at line 310 is probably not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meed to add

```
<!DocType html>
```

Above your page start, which will select document mode correctly on IE.

Also you could make your IE browser to render IE9 mode by adding meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! :)

Comment: @MarcinSadowski do accept the answer to close the question..Thanks :)